# Unable to deploy pre built image in app engine standard environment (GCP)

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

My spring boot application was working fine in cloud build & deployed without any issue till September.
Now my trigger fails in gcloud app deploy.

**Step #4: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Deployment cannot use a pre-built image. Pre-built images are only allowed in the App Engine Flexible Environment.**

app.yaml

```
runtime: java11
env: standard
service: service
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
# backend deployment
# Step 1:
  - name: maven:3-jdk-14
    entrypoint: mvn
    dir: 'service'
    args: ["test"]

# Step 2:
  - name: maven:3-jdk-14
    entrypoint: mvn
    dir: 'service'
    args: ["clean", "install", "-Dmaven.test.skip=true"]

# Step 3:
  - name: docker
    dir: 'service'
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/service-base/base", "."]

# Step 4:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/service-base/base"]

# Step 5:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    dir: 'service/src/main/appengine'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', "--image-url=gcr.io/service-base/base"]
    timeout: "30m0s"
# Step 6:
  # dispatch.yaml deployment
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    dir: 'service/src/main/appengine'
    args: ["app", "deploy", "dispatch.yaml"]
    timeout: "30m0s"
timeout: "100m0s"
images: ["gcr.io/service-base/base"]
```

[Cloud build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZriOO.png)

Thanks in advance. Im confused how my build was working fine before & what am i doing wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't deploy custom container on App Engine standard. You have to provide your code and the environment runtime. Then [Buildpack](https://buildpacks.io/) is used to create a standard container on Google Side *(for information, a new Cloud Build job is ran for this)* and deployed on App Engine.

I recommend you to have a look to Cloud Run to use your custom container. It's very close to App Engine (and even better on many points!) and very customizable.

Answer (score 0):

What your `cloudbuild.yaml` comment's refer to as `Step 5` corresponds to the `Step #4` in the error because system begins numbering steps from 0.

The error message is accurate; App Engine standard (!) differs from App Engine flexible in that the latter (flexible) permits container image deployments. App Engine standard `deploys` from sources.

See Google's [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/springboot-helloworld).

It's possible that something has changed Google's side that's causing the issue but, the `env: standard` in your `app.yaml` suggests the build file has changed.